# Demonstration for the equal number of odd and unequal partitions of an integer

Tags: generating-functions, infinity, integer-partitions

I'm having some problems trying to resolve one exercise from *The art and craft of problem solving* by Paul Zeitz. What this problem asks you is to prove that $F(x)$ is equal to 1 for all $x$, where
$$F(x) = (1-x)(1+x)(1-x^3)(1+x^2)(1-x^5)(1+x^3)(1-x^7)(1+x^4)\cdots$$
This would demonstrate that the number of unequal partitions and odd partitions of an integer is the same since the generating function $U(x)$ for the number of unequal partitions of an integer $n$ is
$$U(x) = \sum_{n=0}^\infty u_nx^n = (1+x)(1+x^2)(1+x^3)\cdots$$
and the generating function $V(n)$ for the number of odd partitions of an integer $n$ is
$$V(x) = \sum_{n=0}^\infty v_nx^n = (1+x+x^2+x^3+\cdots)(1+x^3+x^6+x^9+\cdots)(1+x^5+x^{10}+x^{15}+\cdots)\cdots = \frac{1}{(1-x)(1-x^3)(1-x^5)\cdots}$$
and so $F(x)=\frac{U(x)}{V(x)}$

The way the exercise suggests to carry out the demonstration is to prove that $F(x)$ is invariant under the substitution $x\mapsto x^2$. This is easy to chech
$$F(x^2) = \prod_{k=1}^\infty (1-(x^2)^{2k-1})(1+(x^2)^k)=\prod_{k=1}^\infty (1-x^{2k-1})(1+x^{2k-1})(1+x^{2k}) = F(x)$$

Now the idea is to keep iterating the substitution and I guess that the solution is that for values of $x$ such that $|x| < 1$ all the $x$ terms go to $0$, but I see two problems with this:

1. This wouldn't work for values of $x$ greater than $1$ or less than $-1$. We don't care about these values because the function does not converge when evaluated with them? Why?
2. After iterating the substitution $n$ times we get
   $$F(x) = F(x^{2^n}) = \prod_{k=1}^\infty (1-x^{2^n(2k-1)})(1+x^{2^nk})$$
   and although the $x$ terms go to $0$ for the previously mentioned values of $x$ as $n$ goes to infinity, it is still an infinite product and thus an indeterminate form $1^\infty$ (I think) which I haven't been able to resolve.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We already know from OPs derivation
\begin{align*}
F(x)=F\left(x^2\right)=\cdots=F\left(x^{2^q}\right)\qquad\qquad q\in\mathbb{N}_0\tag{1}
\end{align*}

> We set $F(x)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_nx^n$ and obtain from (1) by coefficient comparison
> \begin{align*}
> F(x)&=F\left(x^2\right)\\
> \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}a_nx^n&=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}a_nx^{2n}\qquad\Longrightarrow\qquad a_{2k+1}=0\qquad\forall k\geq 0\tag{2}
> \end{align*}

We see the coefficients of odd powers of $x$ in $F(x)$ are zero. Let's have a look at
\begin{align*}
&a_0+a_1x+a_2x^2+\color{blue}{a_3x^3}+\cdots\\
&\qquad=a_0+a_1x^2+a_2x^4+\color{blue}{a_3x^6}+\cdots\\
&\qquad=a_0+a_1x^4+a_2x^8+\color{blue}{a_3x^{12}}+\cdots\\
&\qquad=a_0+a_1x^8+a_2x^{16}+\color{blue}{a_3x^{24}}+\cdots\\
&\qquad\ \ \vdots
\end{align*}

We observe by iteratively using $F(x)=F\left(x^2\right)=F\left(x^4\right)=\cdots$ that since for instance $a_3=0$, also all coefficients
\begin{align*}
a_6&=[x^6]F(x)=[x^6]F\left(x^2\right)=[x^3]F(x)=0\\
a_{12}&=[x^{12}]F(x)=[x^{12}]F\left(x^4\right)=[x^3]F(x)=0\\
a_{24}&=[x^{24}]F(x)=[x^{24}]F\left(x^8\right)=[x^3]F(x)=0\\
&\ \ \vdots
\end{align*}
and in general all coefficients of the form
\begin{align*}
a_{3\cdot2^q}=[x^{3\cdot 2^q}]F(x)=[x^{3\cdot 2^q}]F(x^{2^q})=[x^3]F(x)=0\qquad\qquad q\geq 0
\end{align*}
are zero. Here we use the *coefficient of* operator $[x^m]$ to denote the coefficient of $x^m$ of a series.

> We conclude: Each natural number $m\geq 1$ has a unique representation
> \begin{align*}
> \color{blule}{m=2^q\cdot r}\qquad\qquad q\geq 0, r\ \text{odd}
> \end{align*}
> as product of a power of $2$ (if $q\geq 1$) with an odd natural number $r$. It follows from (1) and (2)
> \begin{align*}
> \color{blue}{[x^{m}]F\left(x^{2^q}\right)}=[x^{2^{q}r}]F\left(x^{2^q}\right)=[x^r]F(x)\color{blue}{=0}\qquad\qquad q\geq 0
> \end{align*}
>
> Since from OPs representation of
> \begin{align*}
> F(x)=\prod_{k=1}^{\infty}\left(\left(1-x^{2k-1}\right)\left(1+x^k\right)\right)
> \end{align*}
> we also know that $[x^0]F(x)=1$, the claim \begin{align*}
> \color{blue}{F(x)=1}
> \end{align*}
> follows.

Comment: Wow, this is great, thanks for the answer. Just a question, where it says highlighted in blue "[x^m]F(x^2q)" shouldn't it be "[x^m]F(x)"?

Comment: @Gleck: You're welcome. The argument of $F$ is $x^{2^q}$ because we iteratively double the exponent of $x$. See also the line starting with $a_{3\cdot 2^q}$.